# Android soft keyboard hides split bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that loads a fragments at runtime. When I start the application, the activity loads a fragment with an EditText. I use ActionBarSherlock with splitActionBarWhenNarrow so I have a split bar (an action bar at the botton of the screen). When the EditText get focus and the soft keyboard is loaded, it goes on top of the split bar, hiding it. On the action bar I also use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and I use the dropdown menu to load another fragment. When I load the other fragment, the lower action bar appears correctly on top of the soft keyboard, even if I go to the other fragment, at it keeps working correctly. I'll add some screenshot to clear it up:

First fragment loader, split bar not visibile with soft keyboard

[image]

After loading the second fragment using action bar navigation

[image]

Reloading another fragment, action bar still visibile

[image]

I tried with a test project with minimal code just to load the fragment and the behavior is the same, the split bar is hidden by the soft keyboard.
How can I make it show the split bar from the beginning?

Edit: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" doesn't change anything in this behavior

Activity layout:

```
<it.bem.remailr.MyFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/bg_no_repeat"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Fragment layout:

```
<it.bem.remailr.MyRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:hint="@string/text_hint"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" >
</EditText>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't just that the split action bar is being hidden by the spelling suggestions?

Comment: I thought so looking at the screenshots, but after I load the second fragment and go back to the edit one, if I click on the EditText the spelling suggestion appears without hiding the split bar. On an unrelated note, thanks for you book!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried posting a layout request to the main thread immediately following the input method being shown? You can determine whether the input method is shown/hidden by overriding the `onSizeChanged()` callback in your root `View`. As a dirty proof of concept, you could just post that layout request after a given duration (ensuring that you show the input method beforehand).

You could also use the [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) to run `hierarchyviewer` **on your device, not emulator** in order to determine what `View`s are present (that is, if the candidates are covering the split Action Bar). From what I remember though, the candidate views are added to the root `Dialog` that contains the `KeyboardView` anyway, so it's likely the split Action Bar is just under the space bar, as it were, rather than under the candidate view.

In order to implement `onSizeChanged()` you must extend the `ViewGroup` class that is at the root of your `View` hierachy. For example, you may have a `LinearLayout` as your root `ViewGroup` and all your `View`s are children of this. What you do then is create a new class called `MyLinearLayout` that extends `LinearLayout`, put `MyLinearLayout` as your root `View` in the xml file, and then implement the `onSizeChanged()` callback. It will then be called by the System when the input method is shown.

Comment: I tried hierarchyviewer, but I can't see the keyboard on it. Issuing a requestLayout from hierarchyviewer doesn't change anything. How can I override onSizeChanged() on the root View? Isn't the root view the fragment layout? I think I'm making some stupid mistake here otherwise someone else should have noticed this.

Comment: I've updated the answer relating to the onSizeChange() query. When you say you've tried hierarchyviewer, was this in an emulator?

Comment: Thanks. I put a logger in onSizeChanged() to see when it's called: when I start the application and click in the EditText, the keyboard is showed and onSizeChanged() is NOT called. If I go through the navigation process like in the screenshots, then everytime the keyboard is showed, onSizeChanged() is called. This happens both on my phone and on the emulator. For hierarchyviewer I used the phone.

Comment: Would you be able to post your layout file (or a simplified version of it)? Just to review: you've got one Activity and two Fragements? The first Fragment has an EditText, and the other what looks like a ListView. I'm interested in the first one. Is the EditText height match_parent? What about your Acvitiy layout? What's that look like? Is it just a ViewRoot to which you add your Fragment layouts?

Comment: I'll post the layout in a min. It's very simple though. The same thing happens on a test app with only an activity, that's why I think I'm doing something very wrong :p

Comment: Added the layouts to the original question. I tried also changing the EditText to wrap_content with the same results. I add the fragments at runtime. "AdjustPan" was just a test, doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: A quick thing to try: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" should be set on the Activity, not on a given View. Try moving that line to the Manifest (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Edit: it's adjustResize, with that on the activity, it works. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19358/discussion-between-james-and-alex)